# Pre- or post-filtering for image doubling

Tags: filter-design, upsampling

I am doubling the resolution of images by bilinear resampling (which amounts to averaging). I seem to understand that this should be combined to a sharpening filter for better quality of the reconstruction.

Should the sharpening be applied before or after resampling ? How to design this filter (preferably a very simple one).

How can I theorize this problem ?